# Find all peaks in a matrix NxN

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, search, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create an algorithm using the straightforward approach to find **all peaks** in a N x N matrix. But I am facing some issues with the corners, the first and last row, and first and last column.  I'm considering the problem as it follows:

```
[ ][c][ ][ ] a is considered a 2d peak
[d][a][e][ ] or a hill iff a >= b,
[ ][b][ ][ ] a >= d, a >=c, a >=e
[ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

However, when I need to evaluate the corners as the representation bellow, c and d don't exist. I have to evaluate too many conditions in order to get to something more generic. i.e, for the **a** bellow, I'll need to check if the position **a** is valid if `row-1 < 0`, then I wouldn't need to check anything above **a** and if **col-1** < 0 anything is in the left side of a.

```
[a][e][ ][ ] 
[b][ ][ ][ ] 
[ ][ ][ ][ ] 
[ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

But when we take **a** to the other corners or even evaluating the other positions such as **e** in the example above, I need to certify myself if **e** is in a valid position where **row-1** exists to prevent evaluating that position and get an error (in the example above I'd surely get an error checking if `e >= the element in row-1`. I've implemented a piece of code considering the corners, lines 0 and n and columns 0 and n but I stopped and started thinking on how to make it more readable and simple.

```
void find_hill(){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            //check corners
            if(i-1 < 0){
                if(j-1 < 0){
                   //check if arr[i][j] >= arr at i,j+1 and i+1,j
                }
                if(j+1 > n-1){
                   //check if arr[i][j] >= arr at i,j-1 and i+1,j 
                }
            }                
        }
    }     
}
```

I would like to discuss how could I come up to a solution here. Where should I start from to get something simple? I've thought somehow using an approach similar to the flood fill, but it fills each position separately, probably it wouldn't work since I'd end up in the same problem!

Comment: You could write a function `get(i, j, n)`, which returns `arr[i][j]` if `i` and `j` are valid and `INT_MIN` otherwise.

Comment: @MOehm Right, but how this solve the point that I need to check i-1, j-1, i+1 and j+1 without making too many expressions for the corners and the top, bottom and sides that doesn't one of its neighbors?

Comment: By moving the conditional check into the function you can just probe all four directions unconditionally in the client code. By making the default value `INT_MIN`, you ensure that the peak test will find peaks on the edges and corners. You still have to check all four neighbours explicitly, though.

Comment: (Look [here](https://ideone.com/g6WUzi) for what I mean. The two answers have similar approaches that avoid distinguishing corner and edge cases.)

Comment: @MOehm Woah! I've got what you mean now. That one solves in O(n^2) and will help me with the divide and conquer approach later. Thank you very much! And by the way. After you exemplify I got that INT_MIN is a constant representing the minimum size of an int in C. I was wondering what you meant before, and what should I define on it. Seems like I know how to handle pointers and don't know the basics such as existing constants for representing size of types.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't explain `INT_MIN` properly. (It's not the miminum size of a int, though, but its minimum possible value. These and similar constants are defined in `<limits.h>`.) I could just have said "a small value that you know is smaller than all oter values in the matrix". If all your values are positive, that value could be 0.

Comment: @MOehm I'm sorry for expressing wrong what I meant. I meant the minimum possible value tbh. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following trick: duplicate the first and last rows and columns, as in :

```
[ ][a][b][c][ ]
[a][a][b][c][c]
[d][d][e][f][f]
[g][g][h][i][i]
[ ][g][h][i][ ]
```

then just have your loops start at 1 and end at n-1.

Comment: For this I'd need to iterate on n + 1 and create a new matrix for solving the problem.

Comment: Which is perfectly fine depending on practical context within which you are solving this problem. Programming, like most arts, is about achieving harmony between various values. Unless you're just challenging yourself for the sake of it, if you've got gigabytes of RAM to spare in practical context, you should write code that is readable, maintainable etc., over code that never wastes a CPU cycle or RAM byte. The latter behaviour is what we call premature optimization. It's not just a waste of your effort, it's actually very counterproductive long term. @KennetEmerson

Comment: (Of course there are plenty of cases where you might need to focus on memory or CPU optimization over other values. It's just that it is definitely not a default, not at all.)

Comment: @szpanczyk I've found way to solve it but it was not readable and maintainable at all. It was just a bunch of if and else inside the for loop. Why you think premature optimization is counterproductive? You suggest coming up with a simple solution, and then optimize it after solving the problem?

Comment: Most of your code base will have negligible impact on your application's performance. There is no easy answer, but the general idea is - you should ensure that complexities of all algorithms fit your practical scenarios properly. This you should have control over from the beginning.

So you should write code that will perform adequately to the order of magnitude form the beginning, because otherwise you might need to rewrite large parts of it in the future. Why? Because if you don't have a general idea of what kind of algorithms should suffice, you will not only have to rewrite the places

Comment: @KennetEmerson ...that prove to be crucial for performance, but likely this will destroy the way this code interacted with the rest and you will have a domino effect.

But that means you should pick the right abstract model for what you're computing, right ways to communicate,technologies, libraries etc. from the beginning. If you know from the beginning that certain computation is going to be a heavy lifting, you should pick the perfect algorithm for it from the beginning and design it's surroundings in submission to it, not otherwise. Sure. But..

Comment: ...you should avoid all kinds of optimizations that you can do quite easily in the future until you are sure they are needed. If you know how to engineer code properly, you will know what needs to be decided from the beginning and what can be written fast first and expanded upon as needed later. That's one of the points - while your code should be "clean" from the beginning, try to avoid writing more of it than strictly necessary. If you need to "scrap it" for performance optimization, it will feel like removing a placeholder. You won't have incurred a cost at all really.

Comment: But why is it counterproductive? If it was just a matter that the gain (negligibly and unobservably better performance) is not worth the cost (your time spent thinking, researching, writing, testing), then I wouldn't call it that.

But you're also creating a longer, less readable code, more lines of code that could have a stupid typo that will pass through compilation, testing and all that, but will turn out to be a hard to solve bug down the road.... More code that someone will need to maintain, read and understand when solving bugs in the future etc. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: It takes experience, not just a lecture like I'm giving you here, to really get it, but basically to simplify it, let's say less is more is very often true. Less code is better, as long as you achieve your goal. And your goal is not to conserve as much resources as possible. What is your goal, is a question with no simple answer of course, but it could be money, knowledge, proving yourself, revolutionizing something etc. whatever it is, you probably won't achieve it by prioritizing one thing over everything else at all cost.

Comment: yet another thing - you prematurely optimize, then it turns out the code you spent A LOT of time polishing does not exactly fit practical scenario and turns out the very core of performance... and now it needs to be completely rewritten, because while it's so good at what it's doing, it's goal is slightly off, it turns out, and if this code is called million times every second on client's machine, it's crucial that it is the best your company can come up with. 

if it was just a few lines that work, there would be no tears to shed over scrapping it

Comment: @szpanczyk I was familiar with some of the things you told me but others not. Thank you very much for the lesson :). Also, I will take in consideration more theoretical answers when comes to give an answer to a problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Within the scope of algorithms, there are several options.

You can increase the size of a matrix. On theoretical level that is a perfectly acceptable option, as it will only increase the amount of memory and number of computations in proportion to the width of matrix. Practically though, if you're working with relatively small matrices, it might increase their size anywhere up to 9-fold (in case of 1x1 matrix increased to 3x3). If you find this inelegant, you'll find a lot of things inelegant, and "solutions" that avoid this kind of inelegance are usually way more inelegant and troublesome than those things too.

Another option is obviously conditional statements within loop. It's perfect on theoretical level, as it does not increase memory at all and only adds a constant to every loop cycle you've already been doing... And practically it does exactly that, it makes every cycle take additional time to check a conditional, so no matter if you're handling a lot of small matrices, or less but larger, you've made this piece of code perform worse. If that code was or is very likely to be a bottleneck or generator of a lot of performance issues, then this is actually the worst option to pick. If it's unlikely to be any of that, then it's a good choice because it shows your intent in explicit and concise manner. So if it's the best choice is up to the context, and you could induce anger in other programmers by using or not using this solution, depending if it's a part of code they just want to read through fast, or is it the part that profiling shows most responsible for low performance of application.

Finally, you can just write separate portions of code for all special cases - check four corners, four edges and the rest of the matrix separately. This will not cause "unnecessary" usage of memory and will lead to fastest working code. Will look horrible to read compared to the other two options though.

That said, I am not tackling the software engineering side of this story here. You can make each of these options look much better, more readable and/or maintainable with various techniques, like fe. the already mentioned in another answer option to create a get(x,y) function that would validate it's input - a variant of the "conditional within loop" scenario.

Comment: Got your point. And I think you are right. Taking in consideration your previous comment about being counterproductive on trying to solve something with premature optimization maybe lead us to close our eyes for simple solutions as  duplicating the first and last row and col. Maybe after what you said I'm probably will start thinking simpler than optimized for further problems. Thank you for the contributions.

Answer (score 0):

this is similar to apply a kernel to an image, like the Sobel filter or others that use a sliding-window approach. Usually, I ignore the borders, but as you want to detect hills on matrix borders you need to identify the window type.

If you don't care about memory copies, you can create a 3x3 window inside the nested for and, if the window is in a corner, fill the corresponding values with the central one. Maybe something like this

```
int window[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        window[1][1] = arr[i][j];
        window[0][1] = (i - 1 < 0) ? window[1][1] : arr[i-1][j];
        window[2][1] = (i == n - 1) ? window[1][1] : arr[i+1][j];

        window[1][0] = (j - 1 < 0) ? window[1][1] : arr[i][j-1];
        window[1][2] = (j == n - 1) ? window[1][1] : arr[i][j+1];

        // Process window
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void find_hill() {

    int i, j, k, l;
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
        
            for(k = i-1; k <= i+1; k++) {
                
                for(l = j-1; l <= j+1; l++) {
                    
                    if( k > 0 && k < n && l > 0 && l < n && (i-k)*(j-l) == 0 && arr[i][j] >= arr[k][l] ) {
                        
                        arr[i][j] is a peak;
                    }
                }
            }                
        }
    }     
}
```

You could also have this condition

```
if( !(k == i && j == l) && k > 0 && k < n && l > 0 && l < n && (i-k)*(j-l) == 0 && arr[i][j] > arr[k][l] )
```

With `!(k == i && j == l)` saving you from running the rest of the condition 1 time out of 9, but adding the weight of having itself runned 9 times out of 9.

In this 1 out of 9 times you would also execute the code inside the condition, so it's probably better to add that `!(k == i && j == l)`

Comment: I think it increases a lot the time complexity of the algorithm which I'm willing to keep on `O(n^2)` at least.

Comment: @KennetEmerson Which complexity do you think this one has?

Comment: If you provide people with working source code for specific homework assignments, what do you think this will lead stackoverflow to become in long term? :)

Comment: I did not think about it @szpanczyk. And maybe it can be a hoomework for another person, but I'm just trying to practice some stuffs I've seen on internet. To be honest, the first class of MIT 6.006 wants a single peak. I'm trying to find all of them.

Comment: @Davide I think O(n^4) am I wrong? k and l for loops will be executed n times also.

Comment: @KennetEmerson I wasn't directing this at you. I just find it that people who answer this kind of specific questions with source code should consider how it affects dynamics of this website. The question is perfectly fine, the answers should however be more theoretical. If somebody is looking for a working source code to solve their problem, they should find stack overflow doesn't work for them, or otherwise there will only be more and more of people who don't come here to learn but to offload.

Comment: Oh got your point and I think you are right. That's why I have also asked for for the point I could start for solving it. :)

Comment: @KennetEmerson analyze the complexity of the code above though. You've got it wrong, this answer is by all means proper.

Comment: Could you explain it more @szpanczyk ?

Comment: How this is not O(n^4) if it will run at least n times in all the four loops.

Comment: @KennetEmerson the loops with `k` and `l` run always 3 times, regardless of the size of `n`

Comment: I'm sorry you're right. I misread  the declarations of k and l.

Comment: @szpanczyk I don't know if giving the solution is against SO ideals, but since the the site gives power to the OP and the OP will be glad of receiving a solution, it's inevitable that solutions will be provided.

Comment: @Davide I think he meant he rather discuss about the possible solutions such as 
Matthieu and the first answer of MOehm than give the solution itself. And on this terms I agree with him :P. I'm not criticizing you for posting the solution, but I prefer to learn the way there than get the problem already solved :).

In the other side, the solution of a small piece of code will need to be adapted to the OP solution. Which I think is also fine, since the OP will need to understand to merge with his/her solution.

Comment: @KennetEmerson Yes but your attempt was already half of the solution provided, so what should I have said? "Your approach is right, just keep trying" or should I have put the code in words? This would have been the same, but with some space for misunderstandings

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, I'm saying that what I think Davide was defending, that is the idea of be more theoretical.

Comment: @Davide - with some space for actual learning. You see, if someone both wants and knows how to properly approach learning on their own, they can learn from your source code. If they don't they can feel like they've learned something, but they haven't. 

If you express the concept, they still need to really understand it and translate it to code.

Anyway, if the only thing there is to do in a question is to provide working source code, you should report the question for locking or removal, not answer it.

Comment: @Davide: Wow. Just wow. I did not judge you, but now I do.

Comment: Anyway my code wasn't even complete. It leaves the action after the conditions unspecified, I guess the OP would need to reverse the conditions and use a flag variable to make it work